# Why are new routes in Laravel not working?

Tags: php, laravel

I have been working on this project of mine now for sometime and has no problem with routes until today.

I have even tried clearing cache and dump autoloading. Nothing seems to be working.

I tried to add a new route today and i got a 404 error. I have also use "get" and "any", all to no avail.

At first, I have tried creating several new routes and I'm still getting the same 404 error. Below is how a part of my web.php looks like.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'role:teacher']], function () {
    Route::any('/testing', 'PagesController@testing');


    Route::resource('/attendance', 'AttendanceController');
    Route::get('/teacher/dashboard', 'TeachersController@dashboard')->name('teacher.dashboard');
    Route::resource('homework', 'HomeworkController');
    Route::resource('/teacher/events', 'EventsController',['names' => 
    'teacher.events']);
    Route::any('/view_students', 'StudentsController@myStudents')->name('view.students');
    Route::resource('results', 'CoursesResultController');
    Route::get('/results/class_course/{id}', 'CoursesResultController@showCourseResult');
    Route::post('/results/class_course/{id}', 'CoursesResultController@saveCourseResult');


});
```

**EDIT**: I have solved the issue. I had to delete the cache files in the bootstrap folder manually. Thanks, guys.

Comment: Which routes aren't working, and what does it show as the URL when you try to access the route?

Comment: all the new routes I've added so far havent worked but the old ones are working. The "/testing" is the lastest route I have just added and that too isnt working

Comment: Let's see your pagescontroller first maybe we can find a clue there.

Comment: `php artisan route:clear`, then `php artisan route:list`.

Comment: Hey guys! I have solved the issue. I had to delete the cache files manually.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with the following:

`Route::resource()` generates all the possible routes for you, hence should be kept as the last possible point.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'role:teacher']], function () {
    Route::any('/testing', 'PagesController@testing');


    Route::resource('/attendance', 'AttendanceController');
    Route::get('/teacher/dashboard', 'TeachersController@dashboard')->name('teacher.dashboard');
    Route::resource('homework', 'HomeworkController');
    Route::resource('/teacher/events', 'EventsController',['names' => 
    'teacher.events']);
    Route::any('/view_students', 'StudentsController@myStudents')->name('view.students');

    /* changes over here
       `Route::resource()` generates all the possible routes for you, hence should be kept as the last possible point.
    */
    Route::get('/results/class_course/{id}', 'CoursesResultController@showCourseResult');
    Route::post('/results/class_course/{id}', 'CoursesResultController@saveCourseResult');
    Route::resource('results', 'CoursesResultController');

});
```

Comment: I have been able to solve the issue. Apparently the cache files in the bootstrap folder were conflicting with the URI in the routes.

Comment: Nope. I just deleted the cache and config files manually from the bootstrap folder